# Laravel form request validation on store and update use same validation

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I create laravel form validation request and have unique rules on that validation.

I want use it on `store` and `update` method without create new form request validation again.

but the problem is when on `store` the id doesnt exist and the validate is passed
and when on `update` i failed the pass the validating because the id is exist on storage

i want to ignore the id on `unique` rules but use same form validate request

what is best practice to check on form validate request class if this action from store or update method to ignore unique id ?

Comment: You can check if there is an input named `_method` with value 'put' or 'patch' to know if its an update request

Comment: I use the method like you. But no problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok.. i can do it like @porloscerros Ψ suggest

```
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string|unique:products|max:255',
        ];

        if (in_array($this->method(), ['PUT', 'PATCH'])) {
            $product = $this->route()->parameter('product');

            $rules['name'] = [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('loan_products')->ignore($product),
            ];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

Comment: Working like charm!!!

Comment: I posted a much cleaner version below. No need for the conditional.
If `$this->route()->parameter('product')` returns null, `Rule::unique('loan_products')->ignore($product)`, will ignore `ignore()`, so it all can be done in one statement. See my post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me.

Laravel unique: third param can exclude the id for example, of the record, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
     'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:products,'.$this->id,      
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function rules()
{
    if (request()->isMethod('post')) {
        $rules = [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2000',
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories'
        ];
    } elseif (request()->isMethod('PUT')) {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name'
        ];
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im using this

```
$validated = $request->validated();
```

use this method:

```
public function createAccount(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validated();
```

instead of something like this:

```
public function createAccount(Request $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);
```

use `php artisan make:request RegisterRequest`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently started doing this. I will name the FormRequest using 'Upsert', so example `UpsertStudentRequest`. And the uniqueness rule can be simplified down to the following. If there is no parameter, it returns null and `ignore()` is just ignored and only `Rule::unique('students')` is enforced.

```php
// UpsertStudentRequest

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'foo' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            Rule::unique('students')->ignore($this->route()->parameter('student')),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because i'm using file upload in update i cant use put so both route are POST that why i use route name

```
    $id= $this->route('product'); 
    $rules= [
        'name' => 'required',
        'sku' =>'required|unique:products,sku,' .$id,
        'image' => 'nullable|image|max:1024', // Max 1MB
    ];
    if(Route::currentRouteName() == "products.store"){
        $rules['sku'] = 'required|unique:products';
    };
  
    return $rules;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you checking the `id` when `store` or `update` in FormRequest? You don't need this. The `id` comes to your controller's method like as parameter. Or laravel will create the model using DI in the your controller's method `public function update(User $user)` and then you can use `$user` like an instance of User model. You may check the `id` in web.php or api.php:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

And I suggest you not to use one FormRequest for two methods. This is bad practice

Comment: Because my rules for `store` and `update` almost same except on `name` id
The name cannot duplicate and when create new product with name `product 1` if not exists on storage i can store it.. but when i want edit the validation failed because duplicate `name` on storage so i need to ignore the product id on storage to pass the validation. So if i make one form request validation it will easy to maintainable.

Comment: ok. You need to make new unique rule for validation this field. Here documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique