# how to create a common FormRequest Class for save and update

Tags: laravel

I have created a FormRequest class with required and unique validation. Can I use the same FormRequest class for both store and update function with different validation

**While Store condition should be**

```
public function rules()
{
    
return 
[
  "name" => "required|unique:brands"
];

}
```

**While updating condition should be (Have to ignore the current row record)**

```
public function rules()
{
    
return 
[
 "name" => "required|unique:brands,id,".$this->id
];

}
```

Comment: this question answers yours [Laravel form request validation on store and update use same validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543013/laravel-form-request-validation-on-store-and-update-use-same-validation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel form request validation on store and update use same validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543013/laravel-form-request-validation-on-store-and-update-use-same-validation)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @bhucho and @Harpal Singh for the links. Based on the answer provided on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543013/laravel-form-request-validation-on-store-and-update-use-same-validation), I found answer for my question.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rule = ["name" => "required|unique:brands"];
    
    if (in_array($this->method(), ['PUT', 'PATCH']))
        $rule["name"].= ",id,".$this->id;
    
    return $rule;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format

`return ["name" => "required|unique:brands,name,".$this->id];`

Comment: I want the validation for both condition. For add and update. your code will work for update. I have found solutions from the comment links and added the answer