# Updating form in Laravel goes wrong

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-request, laravel-form

This may be a very simple question, but I can't figure it out! and that's frustrating.
I do my best to explain everything step by step.

- This a small Todo list project in Laravel 8
- A user can create a Project.
- When user clicks on a created project, he goes to the project page (show page)

**ShowController.php**

```
public function show(Project $project)
 {
    return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
 }
```

- In the show page the user can add comments via a textarea form field.

**show.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('project.update',['project' => $project]) }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
  <textarea name="notes" placeholder="Add notes">{{ $project->notes ?? '' }}</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

- Where it goes wrong is here, by updating the project! as soon as the user enters something in the comments field and clicks save, the form indicates that the following items are required:
- The owner_id, title, description field are required. While the model is sent to the show blade page and then in the form action route.
  What am I doing wrong here?

**UpdateController.php**

```
public function update(ProjectRequest $request, Project $project)
 {
  $validated = $request->validated();
  $project->update($validated);
  return redirect($project->path());
 }
```

**ProjectRequest.php**

```
public function rules(): array
{
  return [
      'owner_id' => 'required',
      'title' => 'required',
      'description' => 'required',
      'notes' => 'nullable',
        ];
```

**web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Projects\CreateController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Projects\IndexController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Projects\ShowController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Projects\StoreController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Projects\UpdateController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('project.index');
Route::get('/projects/create', [CreateController::class, 'create'])->name('project.create');
Route::post('/projects', [StoreController::class, 'store'])->name('project.store');
Route::get('/projects/{project}', [ShowController::class, 'show'])->name('project.show');
Route::put('/projects/{project}', [UpdateController::class, 'update'])->name('project.update');
```

**migration**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('notes')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('owner_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why are there required rules for "owner_id", "title" and "description" and there is just single input for "notes" in form? From where this data should come from? Input "title" is required but there is no "title" in request, so of course validation will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just want to update the comment! Is it possible? Do I have to make a separate validation request just for comment? I thought if I give the Project object to the action form route I will not get validation problems because the project object already contains "owner_id", "title" and "description"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel form request validation on store and update use same validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543013/laravel-form-request-validation-on-store-and-update-use-same-validation)

Comment: @Mohnsen you can make separate form request or determine if it is store or update inside rules function.

Comment: thx for you tip! I will take a look

Comment: @chojnicki Thx for ur tips. Place ur answer here I wilk check it as best answer! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have required rules for fields that does not exist in form. So validation correctly fails.

If you use these rules for storing data, and want different one for updating, then you have at least three solutions:

1. Make separate form request file. So instead `ProjectRequest` do for
   ex. `ProjectUpdateRequest` and `ProjectStoreRequest`.
2. Use single Request, but detect if it is Update or Store inside `rules()` function, and return different rules array based on it. Related question: [Laravel form request validation on store and update use same validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543013/laravel-form-request-validation-on-store-and-update-use-same-validation)
3. Don't use custom FormRequest at all for Update, just make this single validation inside controller `update()` function.
   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Option 2 seems to be best solution, because you will not have to repeat validation rules for "notes" input in multiple places - everything will be in single file.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are not required then take them out of your $required array and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> When injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, you will
> often query the database to retrieve the model that corresponds to
> that ID. Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to
> automatically inject the model instances directly into your routes.
> For example, instead of injecting a user's ID, you can inject the
> entire User model instance that matches the given ID.
> [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

show.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('project.update',['project' => $project->id]) }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
  <textarea name="notes" placeholder="Add notes">{{ $project->notes ?? '' }}</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Also, to update a column, you do not need to validate and update all the columns.

UpdateController.php

```
  public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
     {
      $request->validate([
            'title' => 'nullable|string',
        ]);
      $project->update(['notes' => $request->notes ?? '']);
      return redirect($project->path());
     }
```

Note: Add use Illuminate\Http\Request; to the first UpdateController.php file.