# Adding Parameter From Controller to Validation Request

Tags: php, laravel

I want to devide my controller to several service layer, validation layer, and logical layer.
But I got stuck when I want to send new variable to validation request, my schenario is, if there is a new sent it indicates for new data, and if new variable is not exists it indicates it's updating data.

**Here is my Controller:**

```php
    public function store(AlbumRequest $request, AlbumService $service)
    {
        $request->add(['new' => true])
        try{
            $service->store($request);
            return redirect(route('admin.web.album.index'));
        }catch(\Exception $err){
            return back()->withInput()->with('error',$err->getMessage());
        }    
    }
```

**Here is my Request**

```php
class AlbumRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        dd($this->request->get('new')
    }
}
```

I want to catch variable I have sent from Controller to Request. How to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to know if it is for new or update request, you can probably follow this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61543980/7737270

Comment: This gives me a lot of information, thank you for sharing.

Comment: you want to catch what variable how? what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new parameter in request from controller like that

```
$request->merge(array('new' => true));
```

Comment: No I still couldn't send that variable to request by merge method. Any other solution?

Comment: $request->request->add(['new' => 1]);

try this one please

Comment: Still not sent to AlbumRequest.

Answer (score 0):

before your request reaches your controller , it has to go through AlbumRequest class . so you have to merge that field in AlbumRequest class by using method  **prepareForValidation** :

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'new' => true,
    ]);
}
```

add this method in your AlbumRequest class and see if it works

Comment: So there is no way to send variable from Controller?

Comment: only if you make validation yourself in the controller using Validation facade instead of using a AlbumRequest class . that way by using $request->merge(['new'=>true]); in the controller you will get to your point

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do that because the incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called. Now if you want to know whether the request is for creating something new or updating something, you can do it by accessing the route parameters and method type

```php
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'something' => 'required',
    ];

    if (in_array($this->method(), ['PUT', 'PATCH'])) {
        //it is an edit request
        //you can also access router parameter here, $this->route()->parameter('other thing');

        $rules['somethingelse'] = [
            'required',
        ];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can enter the requested class as URL params.

```
    class AlbumRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        dd(request()->get('new')
    }
}
```